# return undefined fetch inside AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I have a react-native app where I do a call to an api where it should return the JSON but I'm just having undefined.

```
export function fetchFromAPI() {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('@token', (errToken, token) => {
    let token = null;

    const requestBody = { token: token };

    return fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJSON) => {
      console.log(responseJSON); // <-- this shows the correct JSON data
      return responseJSON;
    }).catch((error) => {
      // console.error(error);
    });
  });
}
```

I also call that funcion like this:

```
const apiData = fetchFromAPI();
```

If I do console.log() inside the fetch function, it returns the JSON data but if I do to apiData, it just gets undefined.

Does anyone has some idea why its like this, I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: There is no `return` from the function. A return from the callback doesn't return to the outer function. Also `fetch()` is ***asynchronous***

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? I’ve also tried to put a return on fetch() but the return is also undefined. Maybe because it’s asynchronous as you said. How could I make it work? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Promise` to get response from `fetchFromAPI` function, like

```
export function fetchFromAPI() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('@token', (errToken, token) => {
      let token = null;

      const requestBody = {
        token: token
      };

      return fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJSON) => {
          console.log(responseJSON); // <-- this shows the correct JSON data
          resolve(responseJSON);
        }).catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  });
}
```

When calling the `fetchFromAPI`, use `await`, like

```
const apiData = await fetchFromAPI();
```

You can also use `.then` to capture the response and store it in the `state`, like

```
fetchFromAPI.then((data) => {
   // use data here
});
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to return the Promise created by `getItem`:

```
export function fetchFromAPI() {
  return AsyncStorage.getItem('@token', (errToken, token) => {
    let token = null;

    const requestBody = { token: token };

    return fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJSON) => {
      console.log(responseJSON); // <-- this shows the correct JSON data
      return Promise.resolve(responseJSON); // <-- this wraps the JSON into a Promise
    }).catch((error) => {
      // console.error(error);
    });
  });
}
```

Then you need to call the function like this:

```
fetchFromAPI().then(apiData => {...
```